# How to share LineLegend among sub-figures in GraphicsGrid?

Tags: graphics, legending, plotting

Using `GraphicsGrid`, I have put two figures that share the same x-axis in a row. However, I failed to let them share a common `LineLegend`.

The code is (codes about subgraphs `oniplot` and `cpplot` are given later):

```
Legended[
    GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[oniplot], Graphics[cpplot]}}],
    Placed[LineLegend[{"factor = 2", "factor = 3", "factor = 4", "factor = 5"}], Above]
        ]
```

As shown in the following figure, `LineLegend` has been produced as *a text rather than a legend*.

[image: linelegend]

> Question: How to share `LineLegend` among sub-figures in `GraphicsGrid`?

---

---

For subgraph `oniplot`:

```
onireplica2data = { {10, 0}, {20, 0}, {50, 0}, {100, 0}, {150, 0}, {200, 0} };
onireplica3data = { {10, N[199.0 / 172309]}, {20, N[124.0 / 193971]}, {50, N[224.0/ 290346]}, {100, N[311.0/ 400617]}, {150, N[314.0/ 449031]}, {200, N[291.0/481764]} };
onireplica4data = { {10, N[9.0 / 275350]}, {20, N[37.0 / 322928]}, {50, N[12.0 / 554718]}, {100, N[17.0 / 768261]}, {150, N[70.0 / 822346]}, {200, N[9.0 / 959027]} };
onireplica5data = { {10, N[208.0 / 637379]}, {20, N[168.0/732348]}, {50, N[199.0/1029314]}, {100, N[270.0/1372560]}, {150, N[261.0/1610192]}, {200, N[261.0/1610192]} };

oniplot = ListPlot[ {onireplica2data, onireplica3data, onireplica4data, onireplica5data}, 
    Frame -> True, Joined -> True,
    PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15},
    FrameLabel -> {"Async (ms)", "Proportion"},
    FrameTicks -> {{10, 20, 50, 100, 150, 200}, Automatic},
    FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
    PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

For subgraph `cpplot`:

```
cpreplica2data = { {10, 200000}, {20, 200000}, {50, 200000}, {100, 200000}, {150, 200000}, {200, 200000} }; 
cpreplica3data = { {10, 172309}, {20, 193971}, {50, 290346}, {100, 400617}, {150, 449031}, {200, 481764} };
cpreplica4data = { {10, 275350}, {20, 322928}, {50, 554718}, {100, 768261}, {150, 822346}, {200, 959027} }; 
cpreplica5data = { {10, 637379}, {20, 732348}, {50, 1029314}, {100, 1372560}, {150, 1610192}, {200, 1610192} };

cpplot = ListPlot[{cpreplica2data, cpreplica3data, cpreplica4data, cpreplica5data},
    Frame -> True, Joined -> True,
    PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15},
    FrameLabel -> {"Async (ms)", "Numbers"},
    FrameTicks -> {{10, 20, 50, 100, 150, 200}, Automatic},
    FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
    PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add the index for the colors to [`LineLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineLegend.html?q=LineLegend)

```
Legended[Grid[{{Show[oniplot], Show[cpplot]}}], 
  LineLegend[97, {"factor = 2", "factor = 3", "factor = 4", "factor = 5"}]]
```

> [image: Plot]

In order to have the legend above the plots and with markers:

```
Legended[GraphicsGrid[{{oniplot, cpplot}}], 
 Placed[LineLegend[97, Array["factor = " <> ToString@# &, 4, 2], 
 LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Above]]
```

> [image: Plot3]

Comment: but then you lose markers, or you need to input them manually in legend.

Comment: @funnypony to get the makers one just has to add the option `LegendMarkers -> Automatic` to `LineLegend`.

Comment: Wrapping the plots with `Show` is unnecessary in later versions of Mathematica (since v6?).