# How to share `ChartLegends` among multiple `BoxWhiskerChart`s in `GraphicsGrid`?

Tags: graphics, legending, plotting

First, create two `BoxWhiskerChart`: `box1` and `box2`

```
data = { {{1, 2, 5}, {7, 2}},  {{5, 7, 2, 2, 5}, {7, 2, 5}} }
style = Sequence[{
  {"Whiskers", Dashed},
  {"Outliers", None},
  {"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[White]}},
  ChartStyle -> 56,
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  ChartLabels -> {{"A", "B", "C"}, None}];

box1 = BoxWhiskerChart[data, style]
box2 = BoxWhiskerChart[data, style]
```

Then put them together using `GraphicsGrid` and add `ChartLegends` for them using `Legended`:

```
boxes = Legended[
  GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[box1], Graphics[box2]}}],
  ChartLegends -> Placed[{"x", "y"}, "Row"] ]
```

However, it does not produce the legends:

[image: boxes]

> How to share `ChartLegends` among multiple `BoxWhiskerChart`s in `GraphicsGrid`?

---

*Related post:*

I have encountered a similar problem [How to share `LineLegend` among sub-figures in `GraphicsGrid`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66552/22068). However, the answer there does not work here.

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to share LineLegend among sub-figures in GraphicsGrid?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66552/125)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code from the previous question's answer seems to work just as well here with the use of [`SwatchLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SwatchLegend.html):

```
Legended[GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[box1], Graphics[box2]}}], 
 Placed[SwatchLegend[56, {"A", "B"}, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Above]]
```

[image]